Cannot open a gtlf file on html using three js
I am looking to open a 3D image I downloaded from Sketchfab and make it interactive and clicakble using three js. I have followed the instructions by ChatGPT, so I have all the scrypts I need in the folder (GLTFLoader.js, main.js, OrbitControls.js, three.module.js, index.html, and the image itself (gltf format) . I am using a local server from Visual studio code and there is no error message appearing in the developers tool, however the website is blank and I cannot see the image.
I have tried python -m https.server -> same blank screen
I have tried different images in gltf and glb format
Also, ChatGPT suggested I use simple geometric structures like a cube, but it still doesn't work
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from './GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './OrbitControls.js';

// Initialize scene, camera, and renderer
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Add lighting
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(directionalLight);

// Load the brain model
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('models/brain_model.gltf', (gltf) => {
    const brain = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(brain);
    brain.rotation.y = Math.PI; // Initial rotation
}, undefined, (error) => {
    console.error('An error happened while loading the model:', error);
});

// Set camera position
camera.position.z = 5;

// Add orbit controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;

// Animation loop
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

// Handle window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Interactive Brain</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type= "/module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Directory structure
    threejs-brain-project/
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── three.module.js
├── GLTFLoader.js
├── OrbitControls.js
└── models/
    └── brain_model.glb


Could you show code, would be easier to diagnose?

Added the main.js code, but apparently there is no error when I tried to debug

Could you show your folder tree and html file?

Try like this:
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

and imports/or
import * as THREE from "https://esm.sh/three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "https://esm.sh/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://esm.sh/three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

